# Calling Excel Macro From Outlook Freezes Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am having a very difficult time creating an Outlook Macro that opens a file, calls an excel macro, and saves a draft email.

In terms of process--I know it would be much easier just to have an Excel macro send a mail rather than switching between programs, but that is not possible right now due to large files and other constraints that aren't important.

Here is the Outlook Code

```
Sub bodeemail()
    Dim ExApp As Excel.Application
    Dim ExWbk As Workbook
    Set ExApp = New Excel.Application
    Set ExWbk = ExApp.Workbooks.Open("X:\Dropbox\xxxx\xxxx.xlsm")
    ExApp.Visible = False

    ExWbk.Application.Run "Module1.BodeFlash"

     ExWbk.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

Here is the Excel code.

```
Sub BODEFlash()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Email 2.0").Activate
    bode = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, "AG")
    bodetext = Format(bode, "#,###")

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    Dim signature As String
    Dim tstamp As String
    Dim strBody As String


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    ' Subject location
    tstamp = "Subject " & Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    OutMail.Display
    signature = OutMail.HTMLBody

    ' Change change email list here


    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "foo@bar.com" 
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = tstamp
        .HTMLBody = "Flash Approved. " & bodetext & vbNewLine & signature
        .Save
    End With

    'Tidy Up

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Set OutMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have a feeling that this has to do with an Object Library or a DoWhile clause, but haven't been able to pin it down. The macro runs, creates the email, and immediately freezes outlook (have to restart in task manager).

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: When you restart oulook, is your draft saved? Is it possibly the `.Save` line crashing it?

Comment: set your `Objects` to `Nothing`, see if that helps- Example `Set ExApp = Nothing`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can seem from your code is that Outlook is still waiting on excel. and thus will never break out of this: `ExWbk.Application.Run "Module1.BodeFlash"`

I would suggest putting on the end of your excel code:

```
Application.Quit
```

and see if that works. it should quit completly quit the excel application but I have no idea if it closes outlook as well.